# ArcGIS - Merge error after Iterate Feature Selection in model builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I would like to use the model builder to solve OD Cost Matrix in iterations because my origins/destinations FC need to be grouped by attributes. I use the Iterate Feature Selection tool to do so. After performing all OD Cost Matrix in loop, I want to merge all result lines into a single FC and export its table into an excel sheet.

I separate the Iteration part of the process into a subModel with a Collect Values as output:

[image]

Then I use the subModel output into another model to do the merge and the export to excel:
[image]

The subModel seems to run in iteration correctly, but when it's time to merge the output I got these errors:

```
      ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Merge). Parameters are not valid.
      ERROR 000400: duplicate input not allowed
```

Can someone have an idea what is  incorrect in my process?

Comment: I know this sounds stupid, but if you delete both the submodel and merge from your model, then add them back in again (from scratch, not a copy of  what you just deleted), then it may work.  After all, this is simply an issue with input/output names correct?  

At least for myself, this has been a fix in the past.

Comment: Yes I think its because I save all output with same name, so I'll try using %Value% in the name

Comment: Good idea.  Let us know if that worked

Comment: See my solution below, maybe you can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that outputs from iterator in subModel had always the same name ie: `"Lines"`.

My solution is to save every output of subModel in a new FC named with the group by value `%Value%` using [inline variable substitution](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/inline-variable-substitution.htm)

You can see the solution in the red square below:

[image]